# SQL Querying Job Activity Monitor for Status

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a query to find the current status of a SQL Agent Job.  This field exists under the "Status" column in Job Activity Monitor.  See screenshot below:

[image]

I'm using the queries found on [this site](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/) (query also below), which are great but the status it returns is the status of a job that has already been run.

Does anyone know of a way to query the current status vs. the status the job ended at?  In the example above I would want to return "Executing 1(Run Query)".  "Run Query" is the name of step 1 of the job.

```
SELECT 
    [sJOB].[job_id] AS [JobID]
    , [sJOB].[name] AS [JobName]
    , CASE 
        WHEN [sJOBH].[run_date] IS NULL OR [sJOBH].[run_time] IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST(
                CAST([sJOBH].[run_date] AS CHAR(8))
                + ' ' 
                + STUFF(
                    STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBH].[run_time] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                        , 3, 0, ':')
                    , 6, 0, ':')
                AS DATETIME)
      END AS [LastRunDateTime]
    , CASE [sJOBH].[run_status]
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Running' -- In Progress
      END AS [LastRunStatus]
    , STUFF(
            STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBH].[run_duration] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                , 3, 0, ':')
            , 6, 0, ':') 
        AS [LastRunDuration (HH:MM:SS)]
    , [sJOBH].[message] AS [LastRunStatusMessage]
    , CASE [sJOBSCH].[NextRunDate]
        WHEN 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST(
                CAST([sJOBSCH].[NextRunDate] AS CHAR(8))
                + ' ' 
                + STUFF(
                    STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBSCH].[NextRunTime] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                        , 3, 0, ':')
                    , 6, 0, ':')
                AS DATETIME)
      END AS [NextRunDateTime]
FROM 
    [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] (NOLOCK) AS [sJOB]
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    [job_id]
                    , MIN([next_run_date]) AS [NextRunDate]
                    , MIN([next_run_time]) AS [NextRunTime]
                FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules] (NOLOCK)
                GROUP BY [job_id]
            ) AS [sJOBSCH]
        ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBSCH].[job_id]
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    [job_id]
                    , [run_date]
                    , [run_time]
                    , [run_status]
                    , [run_duration]
                    , [message]
                    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                                            PARTITION BY [job_id] 
                                            ORDER BY [run_date] DESC, [run_time] DESC
                      ) AS RowNumber
                FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory] (NOLOCK)
                WHERE [step_id] = 0
            ) AS [sJOBH]
        ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBH].[job_id]
        AND [sJOBH].[RowNumber] = 1
WHERE [sJOB].[job_id] = '527BA180-A5D9-4492-98F0-705889EBCFC4'
ORDER BY [JobName]
```

Comment: I know nothing about SQL Agent, but I'd run an SQL Profiler to see the actual query that is run on the server to get the result set that you see on the screenshot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The table which holds the status information is actually an extended stored procedure called `xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs`. It is accessed through `sp_help_job` which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186722.aspx). If you call `sp_help_job` with no paramters, it will include the columns `current_execution_status` and `current_execution_step` which is what you are after.

If you do a little digging inside `sp_help_job`, you can see that `xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs` is called with the following parameters:

```
IF ((@@microsoftversion / 0x01000000) >= 8) -- SQL Server 8.0 or greater
    INSERT INTO @xp_results
    EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs @can_see_all_running_jobs, @job_owner, @job_id
ELSE
    INSERT INTO @xp_results
    EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs @can_see_all_running_jobs, @job_owner
```

You can take this further, copy the structure of the temporary table and call it yourself so that you can then cherry pick the results:

```
declare @job_name sysname = 'fill in your jobname here';
declare @job_id uniqueidentifier = (select top 1 job_id from msdb..sysjobs where name = @job_name);
declare @job_owner sysname = (SELECT SUSER_SNAME());
declare @xp_results TABLE (
    job_id                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    last_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,
    last_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,
    next_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,
    next_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,
    next_run_schedule_id  INT              NOT NULL,
    requested_to_run      INT              NOT NULL, -- BOOL
    request_source        INT              NOT NULL,
    request_source_id     sysname          COLLATE database_default NULL,
    running               INT              NOT NULL, -- BOOL
    current_step          INT              NOT NULL,
    current_retry_attempt INT              NOT NULL,
    job_state             INT              NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @xp_results
    EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, @job_owner, @job_id

SELECT sj.name,
    case xpr.job_state when 1 then 'Executing: ' + cast(sjs.step_id as nvarchar(2)) + ' (' + sjs.step_name + ')'
        when 2  then 'Waiting for thread'
        when 3 then 'Between retries'
        when 4  then 'Idle'
        when 5  then 'Suspended'
        when 7  then 'Performing completion actions'
    end as [status]
FROM @xp_results                          xpr
inner join msdb..sysjobs sj on xpr.job_id = sj.job_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sjs ON ((xpr.job_id = sjs.job_id) AND (xpr.current_step = sjs.step_id)),
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view                sjv
WHERE (sjv.job_id = xpr.job_id)
```

Note that if you just leave @job_name as null, it will return for all jobs.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I normally use this query to check job run status, are you looking this? This is from msdn as well

```
SELECT sj.Name, 
CASE
    WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NULL THEN 'Not running'
    WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL THEN 'Running'
    WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NOT NULL THEN 'Not running'
END AS 'RunStatus'
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity sja
ON sj.job_id = sja.job_id
WHERE session_id = (
SELECT MAX(session_id) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity);
```

Comment: Thanks Kannan, that's a pretty good workaround, and I could change it up a bit to get closer to what I need, but I'm more looking to query whatever table houses that exact text in the "Status" field.  In the example in my question, I want to find "Executing: 1 (Run Query)"

Answer (score 0):

USE msdb
EXEC dbo.sp_help_job

execution_status is a parameter in the SP.

Value     Description

- 0      Returns only those jobs that are not idle or suspended.
- 1      Executing.
- 2      Waiting for thread.
- 3      Between retries.
- 4      Idle.
- 5      Suspended.
- 7      Performing completion actions.

exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_job 
@execution_status = 1